# Access a document library in a site from another site with same site-collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, web-part, document-library, site-collection

Suppose I have two sites (under the same site collection), first is ABC.sharepoint.com/teams/siteA and second is ABC.sharepoint.com/teams/siteB and I have document library with documents and its metadata in siteA.

Now, I want to use document library of siteA to view metadata in document library web part of siteB page. I tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TntwRm78b_4) but it didn't work.

So, is there any way that I can access data of document library of siteA in siteB without copying into siteB. In the worst case I need to create document library(with views) and upload documents in siteB right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Modern page or Classic page?

For Modern page, you could use the Embed web part:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8

For classic page, use the page viewer web part:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-a-web-page-folder-or-file-on-a-classic-sharepoint-page-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527

Comment: I am using modern page and but if I use Embed web part then problem is I can't connect the document library with File viewer web part to preview documents in the home page.
Let me know if there any solution which allow me to connect File viewer web part with other site's document library views.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use the custom spfx [content query webpart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-content-query-webpart), an instructions on how to extract and build it is that link also. Though you would still need to have a handlebar templates which is another thing to research on but its worth a try.

If you are still not satisfied or if there is still a lack / limitations on what you wanted to achieve, I suggest you look into custom spfx development to create your own webpart, see it [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Hope this information helps! Happy Learning!